# Android pass image drawable via intent in activity to 2nd activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, imageview

In my intent I want to pass an image drawable to a second activity or in this case a detail view. I pass the image drawable like this from activity1

```
Intent i = new Intent(NewsActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
i.putExtra("image",R.drawable.bg1);
```

bg1 is a png file in the app package in the drawable dir.

In the second activity I try to set the image like the below.

```
int imageId = getIntent().getIntExtra("image", 0);

//Image background
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.detailBgImg);
imageView.setImageResource(imageId);
```

I would expect the imageView to be the passed the drawable from activity1 i.e R.drawable.bg1

Also this line confuses me.

```
int imageId = getIntent().getIntExtra("image", 0);
```

I presume getIntExtra("image" is the key that was passed from activity1 what is this default value that I have set to 0? I don't get this? Please explain.

Either way my passed image never shows if I hard code the drawable it does like the below

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.detailBgImg);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.bg1);
```

I am very confused! I am new to Android also so that doesn't help.

Comment: Ahhhh I am an idiot would help if I was looking in the right view. Tired and a couple tinnies doesn't help lol. It all works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

FIRST: 0 will be used when you don't pass "image" key in your intent as the default value for the imageId

SECOND: Your code seems to be ok and doesn't have any problems.. If you can't see the image even after hardcoding as you said, I thing your drawable (bg1) is too large to be displayed (or something like that) or perhaps something is wrong with your imageView and layout.....

Comment: Silly me looking in the wrong view lol. Thanks for the explanation about the 0 defaultValue. So in other words if it couldn't find my drawable that I pass it would use what ever the default is in this case 0.

Answer (score 1):

The second arguments means default value if in case your intent with a key "image" does not exist.

```
int imageId = getIntent().getIntExtra("image", 0);
```

In your code it is much better if you utilize this paramater like this.

```
int imageId = getIntent().getIntExtra("image", R.drawable.placeholderimage);
```